# LVM - adding space to /boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I am struggling with an empty 500 G hard drive, and a full 236 M /boot partition :-(
It seems the system has been set up with LVM.

Here is the configuration :

[image]

I found the LVM how to a bit dry :

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/

but found some nicer doc : 
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/40702/how-to-manage-and-use-lvm-logical-volume-management-in-ubuntu/

and being french : 
https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/lvm

All that seems a bit complex to me.
What I would understand is that I would need to first create a Logical Volume, and then add it to /boot.
Would I have to follow all these steps : https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/lvm ?

Seems complicated :-s

Would it be an easy way to add space to /boot ??

Comment: Your `/boot` isn't an lvm logical volume so you can't add space to it easily using lvm. You need to either resize the lvm physical volume to be able to extend the `/dev/sda1` partition, or create a new logical volume (which will require resizing the current logical volumes) and reconfigure your system to use that volume as `/boot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my guess about your disk partitions (synthetic):

```
  sda1                      sda5
-------------------------------------------------------------
| /boot: 236MB (ext2/3/4) | /: 465GB (LVM)                  |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Your boot partition (sda1) is a simple partition at the beginning of your disk and you have another partition after it. You have no way to extend the first one without moving the beginning of the second one.

I advise you to clean up your /boot instead. It will be much  easier. To be as large as 227MB it may contain around four kernels so you can remove one or two. You will easily find some tutorials on this purpose on the web, [like this one](http://tuxtweaks.com/2009/12/remove-old-kernels-in-ubuntu/).

Comment: is it usual to have such a small boot partition ?

Comment: I think /boot is often 256MB to 1GB when it is distinct from the root partition. It can also be a standard folder of the root partition but used to not be merged because bootloaders (lilo, then grub1) were more limited in their partition size and type support. Nowadays grub2 supports most of them.